# msleep(msec) vs msleep_interruptible(msec)

Tags: c, linux, signals, sleep

I don't understand usage for these: `msleep` and `msleep_interruptible` ... I know one interruptible and other is non-interruptible but couldn't find certain usage where I can actually see. I tried calling thread with function to msleep and print say "Hello!" and msleep(msleep_interruptible) after that, but couldn't see any difference. Can anyone help me with that, may be with example?

Comment: Does this help? http://help.lockergnome.com/linux/msleep_interruptible-msleep--ftopict369242.html

Comment: actually I'm not concern about load average (that they are talking in this thread)for now, but I'm not able to understand idea behind these APIs, WHEN to use? (I guess for for WHY, what you're pointing is, I think helpful, later when I want to use!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is in what happens when a signal (e.g. SIGINT) is raised and you set a signal handler for that signal.

- `msleep` goes back to sleep
- `msleep_interruptible` returns to the caller (with a non-zero value representing the sleep time remaining).

---

An example of an interruptible sleep:

```
$ perl -Mthreads -E'
   my $stime=time;
   async { sleep(3); kill INT => $$; }->detach();
   $SIG{INT} = sub { warn "Got INT signal after ".(time-$stime)."\n"; };
   sleep(5);
   say time-$stime;
'
Got INT signal after 3
3
```

It slept for 3 seconds instead of 5 because it got interrupted by a handled signal. The other version would print the following:

```
Got INT signal after 3
5
```

In other words, the signal handler gets called either way, but one version doesn't return even if a signal comes in.

Comment: can you give example which includes what you just said? BTW signal is like what? raise(SIGINT) kind of?